# Terminal IRC client with xterm-256color support

Tags: terminal, irc, xterm

irssi doesn't support 256 colors.  WeeChat doesn't support 256 colors.  BitchX doesn't support 256 colors.

And yet vim, my *text editor*, supports 256 colors.

Am I missing a secret fork of one of the above that has extended color support?  Or has nobody in the history of hacking ever thought to implement this?

Comment: BitchX doesn't support 256 colors because, IIRC its written with ncurses. ncurses only supports 16 foreground and 8 background colors. Same thing with irssi. Source: http://www.guckes.net/irssi/index.html Search the page for "256"

Comment: But that's not true; vim uses ncurses!  ncurses can clearly be compiled with 256-color support: http://www.c-for-dummies.com/ncurses/256color/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's 2014 now and there is a [patch for Irssi](http://anti.teamidiot.de/static/nei/*/Code/Irssi/) to ramp it up to true 24 bit colours.

Answer (score 3):

[WeeChat](http://weechat.org/) 0.3.4 is going to support 256 color terminals and the feature appears to be already implemented in the development version.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "[A (not yet finished) IRC client that runs in 256 Colors](https://github.com/rphillips/irc-256)" found
on github after a quick search, using Python and its ncurses binding.

Generally 256 colors-support seems to remain a "planned feature"
in a lot of console clients, such as weechat.

Answer (score 0):

fwiw, [EPIC5](http://www.epicsol.org/doku.php/epic_news) also supports 256 colours